# After reading 3 story by user ask for subscription popup

Tags: plugins, users, content-restriction

I am new in word-press development, i want to make a news website in which user read two story then ask him to pay(Subscription Plan), when he registered he can read unlimited

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

What you need is a paywall plugin or a membership plugin that will require the visitor to pay or be a member to view your news content.

Check out these plugins:

Restrict User Access
https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-user-access/

Leaky Paywall
https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaky-paywall/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found the ProfilePress metered paywall addon to be very effective for our needs.

Addon page => https://profilepress.com/addons/metered-paywall/

Documentation => https://profilepress.com/article/setup-metered-paywall-wordpress-content/